# openmeeting invitation hash generated via soap not working

Tags: php, soap, drupal, openmeetings

I am working on openmeeting integration for a Drupal site. I was able to successfully generate the invitation hash using the SOAP API provided by openmeeting.

I used **getInvitationHashFullName** API function to generate the hash value.

It returned hash value. Then I created the invitation URL in the format:

http://[host]:5080/openmeetings/swf?invitationHash=[hashvalue]

When I try to access the above link, the page is loading indefinitely, it is not loading the conference.

Here is the reference for API: https://openmeetings.apache.org/openmeetings-webservice/apidocs/index.html?index-all.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL to the room is wrong, it's just http://[host]:5080/openmeetings/?invitationHash=[hashvalue]. Where do you have this URL from ?

Comment: I copied it from the invite to conference option in the meeting room